# Equation relabel then reset

Tags: equations, counters

I have asked a previous question, but that was for cases. Here, I would like to relabel some equations midway before resetting the labelling set to default.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
%\usetheme{Singapore}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usefonttheme[?options?]{structuresmallcapsserif}
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{203,140,55} % changed this
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,102,102} % changed this
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,153,153} % changed this
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\begin{document}
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------New slide ----------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{frame}{Sample}
        \setcounter{equation}{10}
        \begin{equation}
            F = ma
        \end{equation}
        % Starting from here I would like 11a, 11b,...
        \begin{align}
            a + b &= c\\
            d + e &= f
        \end{align}
        \begin{equation}
            a = 1
        \end{equation}
        % Starting from here, I would like 12, 13,..
        \begin{equation}
            f = 5
        \end{equation}
        \begin{equation}
            F = -kx
        \end{equation}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Is there a way to freeze the current equation number `n` and start labeling some equations as `(na) (nb)...` and so on?

Comment: Hmmmm might if you post a solution on how to do so, especially on how to freeze the current equation number?

Comment: Ok, got it. But how to save the current equation number and tagging it with the letter suffix?

Comment: oh you meant the current number not a literal n. I'll delete the comments

Comment: I was using a literal `n` as a description, just saying.

Comment: you could use `\tag{\theequation a}`

Comment: Oh, ok. Is there a way to automate the increment of letters while retaining the equation number instead of typing each letter for the equations?

Comment: The `subequations` facility may be useful here.  This question has examples: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/407290.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `subequations`; the label should be unique for each use of the environment.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
%\usetheme{Singapore}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usefonttheme[?options?]{structuresmallcapsserif}
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{203,140,55} % changed this
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,102,102} % changed this
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,153,153} % changed this
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\begin{document}
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------New slide ----------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{frame}{Sample}
        \setcounter{equation}{10}
        \begin{subequations}\label{freeze}
        \begin{equation}
            F = ma \tag{\ref{freeze}}
        \end{equation}
        \begin{align}
            a + b &= c\\
            d + e &= f
        \end{align}
        \begin{equation}
            a = 1
        \end{equation}
        \end{subequations}
        % Starting from here, I would like 12, 13,..
        \begin{equation}
            f = 5
        \end{equation}
        \begin{equation}
            F = -kx
        \end{equation}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a good answer! What if I have two slides and I want to apply the subequations environment on both slides with the letter suffixes on the second slide following from the previous slide?

Comment: Right now, the answer applies for only one slide. How to apply it to two or more consecutive slides?