# Equation sublabel continuation

Tags: labels, subequations

This is a followup to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549001/equation-relabel-then-reset).

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
%\usetheme{Singapore}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usefonttheme[?options?]{structuresmallcapsserif}
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{203,140,55} % changed this
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,102,102} % changed this
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,153,153} % changed this
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\begin{document}
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------New slide ----------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{frame}{Sample}
        \setcounter{equation}{10}
        \begin{subequations}%\label{freeze}
            Hi:
            \begin{align}
            a + b &= c\\
            d + e &= f
            \end{align}
            Hi
            \begin{equation}
            a = 1
            \end{equation}
        \end{subequations}
    \end{frame}
    
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------New slide ----------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{frame}{Sample}
        \begin{subequations}%\label{freeze}
            Hi:
            \begin{align}
            a + b &= c\\
            d + e &= f
            \end{align}
            Hi
            \begin{equation}
            a = 1
            \end{equation}
        \end{subequations}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Right now, the number increments and the letters start over. I want the equation labels in the second slide to be (11d), (11e), and (11f). How to do this?

Comment: The easiest way is to stay within the same `subequations` group and use `\intertext`.

Comment: Hmm can you post a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single set of sub-numbered equations, use a single `{subequations}` environment. To avoid mis-nesting of environments the subequations env must be outside the frames, but that's fine.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper]
%\usetheme{Singapore}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{bm}
%\usefonttheme[?options?]{structuresmallcapsserif}
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{203,140,55} % changed this
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,102,102} % changed this
%\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,153,153} % changed this
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\begin{document}
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------New slide ----------------------------------------------------%
\setcounter{equation}{10}
\begin{subequations}\label{freeze}
    \begin{frame}{Sample}
            Hi:
            \begin{align}
            a + b &= c\\
            d + e &= f
            \end{align}
            Hi
            \begin{equation}
            a = 1
            \end{equation}
    \end{frame}
    
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------New slide ----------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{frame}{Sample}
            Hi:
            \begin{align}
            a + b &= c\\
            d + e &= f
            \end{align}
            Hi
            \begin{equation}
            a = 1
            \end{equation}
            The set of equations \ref{freeze} spans multiple frames.
    \end{frame}
    \end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Note the use of `\label` and `\ref` for referring to the whole set of equations.

If another case arises where subequations *must* span frames but share the frame with ordinary equations, an uglier solution would involve `\setcounter` to carry sub-numbering across environments. Assume you put `\newcounter{subeqnsave}` in the preamble.

```
\begin{frame}{sample}
  \begin{subequations}
...
  \setcounter{subeqnsave}{\value{equation}}% or other...
     % method of saving a counter value; (not \label though)
  \end{subequations}
\end{frame}
%----------------------------------
\begin{frame}{sample}
  \addtocounter{equation}{-1}
  \begin{subequations}
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{subeqnsave}}
...
  \end{subequations}
... another equation ...
\end{frame}
```

Some explanation of that: Outside `subequations` the `equation` counter is just what it says, but *inside* `subequations` it is actually the sub-number (number of letter). That's why the `\addtocounter` before `subequations` returns the main numbering to the previous, whereas the `\setcounter` inside `subequations` adjusts the letter value.

Comment: Nice solution! On a side note, let’s suppose that I want `a=1` in the second slide to be 12. How do I stop the `subequations` labeling mid-frame?

Comment: @Superman it gets messy then. Since you can't interleave environments, you are probably stuck using two separate `{subequations}`, with `\setcounter` thrown in. Can't format it in a comment, so I'll append it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

A series of subequations can be interrupted by `\intertext` to insert some text.  In the following, a 2-line `align` environment is embedded within `gather`, so that all lines are numbered; `aligned` would produce only a single equation number for the group.

```
documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{bm}
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,102,102} % changed this                 
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman                                                        
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\newcounter{savesubeqno}
\begin{document}
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------New slide----------------------------------------------------%                          
    \begin{frame}{Sample}
        \setcounter{equation}{10}
        \begin{subequations}%\label{freeze}                                     
            Hi:
         \begin{gather}
            \begin{align}
            a + b &= c\\
            d + e &= f
            \end{align}\\
         \intertext{Hi}
            a = 1
        \setcounter{savesubeqno}{\arabic{equation}}
         \end{gather}
        \end{subequations}
    \end{frame}

    %-----------------------------------------------------------------New slide----------------------------------------------------%                          
    \begin{frame}{Sample}
            Hi:
        \addtocounter{equation}{-1}
        \addtocounter{savesubeqno}{1}
        \begin{subequations} 
         \begin{gather}
            \begin{align}
            a + b &= c\\
            d + e &= f
            \end{align}\\
          \intertext{Hi}
            a = 1
         \end{gather}
        \end{subequations}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code, slide 1]
[image: output of example code, slide 2]

(It's likely that there is unnecessary code in the above.  I removed only the commented material from the example in the question before recoding the `subequations` block.)

**Update:**

The first try at a response didn't continue the numbering onto the second slide, but restarted it.
These changes have been made to correct it,

- A new counter, `savesubeqno`, is added; in `amsmath`, the same `equation` counter is used for both levels, so its value isn't retrievable after the `subequations` environment is closed.
- The main `equation` counter is decreased by 1 because it was stepped when the display was closed on the first slide.
- The counter for the subequations is *in*creased by 1 because the starting value is what is expected at the beginning of a new display.  (Cf. the setting to 10 at the beginning of the example.)

Comment: The second slide that you posted is the same as mine. You didn’t answer my question on how to make the labels 11d, 11e, and 11f for the second slide.

Comment: @Superman -- I did miss that; sorry.  The answer is updated to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a situation where you want a frame break.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{RGB}{0,102,102} % changed this
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks,noframenumbering]
\frametitle{Sample}
\setcounter{equation}{10}

\begin{subequations}
Hi
\begin{align}
  a + b &= c\\
  d + e &= f
\end{align}
Hi
\begin{equation}
  a = 1
\end{equation}

\pagebreak

\begin{align}
  a + b &= c\\
  d + e &= f
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

Hi
\begin{equation}
  a = 1
\end{equation}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]